# Codeigniter Rest Api Delete using parameter ID

Tags: rest, codeigniter, flutter

I'm Learning CRUD operation with Codeigniter and Rest Api for my app **Flutter**.But I'm get some problem with Delete operation. I'm want delete data using parameter ID , but the message show me ID Null.

It's my Get Operation using parameter

```
http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/get?id=5
```

Possible i'm make delete operation like this ?

```
http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete?id=5
```

I already try

```
http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete/5
http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete/id/5
```

But Nothing change , still ID null.
It's my Controller And Model Rest Api : 
**Controller**

```
public function delete_delete()
    {
        $id = $this->delete('id');
        $msgDelete = ['id' => $id, 'message' => 'Deleted the resource'];
        $msgEmpty = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'ID Not Found'];
        $msgBadRequest = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Provide an ID'];

        if ($id === null) {
            $this->set_response($msgBadRequest, 400);
        } else {
            if ($this->mahasiswa->deleteMahasiswa($id) > 0) {
                $this->set_response($msgDelete, 204);
            } else {
                $this->set_response($msgEmpty, 404);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function deleteMahasiswa($id)
    {
        $this->db->delete('mahasiswa', ['id' => $id]);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing some ambigius things in your code for example the api url is :

```
http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete/5
```

and your controller method name is delete_delete .

If you are using the get method you should respect the following :

```
base_url/controller_name/method_name?id=3
```

and then you can get the value with :

```
$this->input->get('id')
```

otherwise if you are passing the id as a method argument like the following :

```
http://your_domain/controller_name/delete/5
```

you can get the value like this :

```
class controller_name extends CI_Controller {
.
.
.
public function delete($id=null){

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Possible do like this

```
192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete_delete?id=5
```

Controller

```
public function delete_delete() {
 $id = $this->input->get('id');
 $this->mahasiswa->deleteMahasiswa($id);
 redirect('http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa'); 
}
```

Model

```
function deleteMahasiswa() {
 $this->db->where('id', $id);
 $this->db->delete('mahasiswa'); 
}
```

Comment: So my url see like this 192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete_delete?id=5, instead of 192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete?id=5